# Class files not generated in ANT build

Tags: java, class, ant, jenkins, war

I am using a proper build.xml to generate a war file.ANT succeeds in creating a WAR file but without the class files!!.I tried the same from eclipse or cmd prompt but the final war file does not contain the class files only contains the libs etc.
Here is my build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<project name="Westpac" default="war" basedir="C:\\Users\\M1019779\\.jenkins\\workspace\\Test GIT">
    <property name="configuration" value="stage"/>
    <target name="init" depends="clean">
        <mkdir dir="build/classes"/>
        <mkdir dir="build/lib"/>
        <copy todir="build/lib">
            <fileset dir="C:\\java\\wp_lib">
                <include name="*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
    </target>
    <path id="build.classpath">
        <fileset dir="build/lib">
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="compile" depends="init" description="Compiles the java source">
        <echo message="Building for ${configuration}" />
        <javac destdir="build/classes" debug="true" srcdir="src">
            <classpath refid="build.classpath" />
            <!-- <classpath> -->
                <!-- <fileset dir="build/compile"> -->
                    <!-- <include name="**/*.jar" /> -->
                    <!-- <include name="*.jar" /> -->
                    <!-- </fileset></classpath>-->
        </javac>
        <!--must copy non java resources manually-->
        <copy todir="build/classes/">
            <fileset file="src/*.properties" />
        </copy>
        <copy todir="build/classes/conf">
            <fileset dir="src/conf" />
        </copy>
        <copy todir="build/classes/com/bcsg/saas/db">
            <fileset dir="src/com/bcsg/saas/db" />
        </copy>
        <copy todir="build/classes/pdf">
            <fileset dir="src/pdf" />
        </copy>

        <copy todir="build/classes/vmTemplate">
            <fileset dir="src/vmTemplate" />
        </copy>     
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="dist" />
        <delete dir="build" />
    </target>

    <target name="war" depends="compile" description="Packages up the java classes, along with all static assets and the libraries required for runtime into a war file">       
        <war destfile="dist/westpac-${configuration}.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <classes dir="build/classes"/>
            <fileset dir="WebContent"/>
            <fileset file="build/build.properties" />
            <lib dir="build/lib" />
        </war>
    </target>       
</project>
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly when you ask a question.

Comment: Are there any class files in `build/classes` after your build?

Comment: There are no class files after my build

Comment: Do you see `[javac]` in your `build.xml` output?

Answer (score 0):

Your `war` task has a nested `<classes>` element, which [is a FileSet, per the Ant documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html).  That means you can be explicit about what to `<include>`, and identify the .class files.

Try changing your war task to include this:

```
<classes dir="build/classes">
    <include name="**/*.class"/>
</classes>
```

Comment: I doubt that'll make any difference, the default for a `fileset` with `dir` but no include/exclude specifications is to include everything except the "default excludes" (source control metadata, common backup file extensions, etc.)